# Tensor Product: Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

**Reference**

Foundation for: [Hilbert Spaces: Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046329/79762)

**Problem**

Given a vector spaces $V$ and $W$.

Take its algebraic tensor product: $\tau:V\times W\to V\otimes W$

How to prove that the image is proper in general:
$$\mathrm{im}\tau=V\otimes W\iff\dim V\leq1\lor\dim W\leq1$$

*(Presuming only the universal property!)*

My attempt was to consider linearly independent vectors: $v\neq\kappa v',\,w\neq\lambda w'$

For contradiction assuming it holds: $v\otimes w+v'\otimes w'=v_0\otimes w_0$

But from here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you allowed to know anything about a basis for the tensor product?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: My apologiesfor rolling back your edit. I prefer the symbol, here.

Comment: Google tensor rank

Comment: In some fields $a \lor b = \max\{a,b\}$, which makes reading the question as written confusing.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: In any field the wedge denotes an operator with certain universal properties; the logical or, the set union and the order maximum being some of them. ;)

Comment: @Daniel: Ah ok so the simple tensors and higher rank tensors. Do you have nice a link forthis?

Comment: @Thomas: Yep, so by the universal property it induces a basis: $e_k\otimes f_l$

Comment: @Freeze_S See the proposition used in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981056/rank-of-tensors-in-terms-of-ranks-of-associated-linear-maps/981511#981511             The link for the paper is there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity assume that $V$ and $W$ both have dimension $2$ and have bases $\{e_1, e_2\}$ and $\{f_1, f_2\}$ respectively.

I assume that $\tau$ is defined by
$$
\tau (a_1e_1 + a_2e_2, b_1f_1 + b_2f_2) = a_1b_1(e_1\otimes f_1) + a_2b_1(e_2\otimes f_1) + a_1b_2(e_1\otimes f_2) + a_2b_2(e_2\otimes f_2).
$$

Now say that $\tau$ surjective, then there you would have a "solution" to
$$
\tau (a_1e_1 + a_2e_2, b_1f_1 + b_2f_2) = e_1\otimes f_1 + e_2\otimes f_2.
$$
From above this would give you equations
$$\begin{align}
a_1b_1 &= 1 \\
a_2b_1 &= 0 \\
a_1b_2 &= 0 \\
a_2b_2 &= 1.
\end{align}
$$
But this system doesn't have any solutions. So you have a contradiction.

(You can make this more general.)

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks. =D (How do you mean more general?)

Comment: Besides, do you have an idea for the linked thread?